# The Different between android folders(bin, xbin, sbin)

Tags: android

I've noticed that I have some directories inside my android phone which look the same.

What the different between /sbin, /system/sbin, /system/bin, /system/xbin?

Answer (score 28):

1. **`/system`** is the main Android directory for **storing immutable components** generated by the build of the AOSP. This **includes native binaries, native libraries, framework packages**, and stock apps. It’s usually **mounted read-only** from a separate image from the root file system, which is itself mounted from a RAM disk image.
2. Android also includes many directories commonly found in any Linux system, such as **`/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`, `/sbin`, `/root`, `/mnt`, and `/etc`**. These directories often serve similar if not identical purposes to the ones they serve on any Linux system, although they are very often trimmed down, as is the case of `/sbin` and `/etc`, and in **some cases are empty, such as `/root`.**
3. More than 150 command-line utilities are scattered throughout Android’s root file system. `/system/bin` contains the majority of them, but some “extras” are in `/system/xbin`, and a handful are in `/sbin`.
4. **`/sbin`:** In Linux, this would hold binaries essential to the system administrator. **In Android**, it **contains only ueventd and adbd**.
5. **`/bin`:** All **native binaries and daemons** built as part of the AOSP. All modules built with BUILD_EXECUTABLE are here. The only **exception is adbd, which has the LOCAL_MODULE_PATH set to `/sbin`** and is therefore installed there instead.
6. **`/xbin`:** **“Extra” binaries generated** by some of the packages that are built within the AOSP but **aren’t essential to the system’s operation.**

Thanks goes to ***Mr: Karim Yaghmour*** , The great ; ***The author of Embedded Android*** tutorial.

Comment: A practical example that was causing me fits: not one of the utilities nor commands I was using to remount /system as RW was working, at all. But when I used `/system/bin/mount ...` instead of `mount ...` I was able to manually remount as RW. (Presumably /system/xbin/mount is taking priority otherwise.) I got this idea from a reddit post in which the OP eventually fixed his PATH, which I still need to figure out. http://www.reddit.com/r/cyanogenmod/comments/2m9t61/how_do_i_remount_system_rw_on_cm11_m12/

Comment: Where can we put personal commands/scripts so that they are not deleted after reboot (cause no persistent filesystem)?